# IIS ASP.NET - URL Rewrite - FormsAuthentication module fires before RewriteModule module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5, url-rewrite-module

I have one site and 3 applications in 3 virtual folders and 3 app pools.
I use URL rewrite (redirect or rewrite doesn't matter) to catch some wrong urls and rewrite or redirect to appropriate application.
All 3 apps are asp.net MVC and use Forms Auth.
They must use sepparate app pools.

If I use rewrite I have an error that URL can't be served from same app pool, so rewriting doesn't work across app pools, that is a known issue.
If I use redirect there is a problem that before I can issue a redirect from URL rewrite FormsAuth sends redirect for login.
This is scenario where I am already logged in in app1, but I want to redirect from app2 and app2 has no session yet and it redirects me to login of app2 instead that I get URErewrite/redirect to URL in app1.

**Can this be overridden ?**

So that URL Rewrite redirect is not surpassed with FormsAuth redirect.

I tried to put **RewriteModule** in front of **FormsAuthentication** module in main **applicationHost.config** (*C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config*) but it doesn't work :

```
 <modules>
            <add name="IsapiModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="IsapiFilterModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="HttpLoggingModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="HttpCacheModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="StaticCompressionModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="DefaultDocumentModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="DirectoryListingModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="HttpRedirectionModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="StaticFileModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="RequestFilteringModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="CustomErrorModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="FailedRequestsTracingModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="ConfigurationValidationModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="RewriteModule" />
            <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="UrlMappingsModule" type="System.Web.UrlMappingsModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
                <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
                <add name="ScriptModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
                <add name="ApplicationRequestRouting" />
        </modules>
        </system.webServer>
```

**UPDATE ::::::::::::::::::**

I didn't find out a way to overide FormsAuth so I went the ARR route.
I have 4 sites (no more one site and 3 apps/virtualFolders) :
[image]

*_ARR site listens to real ip and virtual host, it is empty , it only has URL rewrite rules, so it is guaranteed that URL rewrites are executed before everithing, the problem of Rewriting to another APP pool is solved by ARR reverse proxy, URL Rewrice at the end causes local reconnection ala reverse proxy, there aro no server farms configured in ARR, only one checkbox (enable proxy).

Other three sites keep 3 versions of app.

There is a file that keeps a record which version is the last installed.
There is a cookie issued for affinity to site/version of app.
All that is handled in custom URL revrite provider.

Cookies with this solution :
[image]

Cookie basicaly has the port writen inside. So URL rewrite sends the user to correct version.

And new logons go to newest version, allready logged in user stays at his current version, and finnaly it works as it needs to work.

All this because as I said before , objects in our Session can't be serialized.

And for existing loggins there is no performance hit in starting up site.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Could you describe the problem you encountered with a specific example, which may be easier to understand.

Comment: I can put concrete rules etc, but ESSENCE of the problem is that I have a rewrite rule that does a redirect. It works in normal ocasions, but in case you are not yet logged in, FormAuth module issues a redirect before a URL rewrite module, so it overides URL rewrite, and I need URL rewrite to be primary here. The problem is that there is FormAuth app in same application/appPool.

Comment: And I can't separate that becaue IIS maps URL fisrt to application and then executes all modules, there is no way around that, only to execute URL rewrite  somehow before everything. I am looking into ARR for this now, that is my fourth solution to this problem.

Comment: The URL rewrite module handles requests before authentication kicks in, you might need URL rewrites to bypass authentication, but that doesn't seem to be easy to achieve. Is it possible to enable both anonymous and forms authentication and then create a rule that authorizes to deny anonymous users and allow authenticated users.

Comment: You are actualy right , but, in our case  even with anonymous access we have the same problem, unfortunately, login page is realy marked for anonimus acces and it wont trigger redirect, BUT, if user click a bookmark of any other page than login , or even the drefault route is problem because it is with auth, then what happens is that FormsAuth redirects to login. There would be no problem if user would allways go to login first.  i solved it differently, see UPDATE